# How to set the value in EditText field?

Tags: android

I have three EditText, I want to concatinate the strings present in the first two EditText fields,and display in the third EditText field.After entering the string at 2nd field,it 
automatically concatinate and set in the third EditText.

```
EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
mtext1=text1.getText.toString();

EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
mtext2 = text2.getText.toString();


mtext3=mtext1.concat().mtext2;
Edit text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text3);
text3 = setText(mtext3.toString());
```

I wrote the above code.But I result is not shomn in the third EditText.
Please give the solution, that I implement in my program

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should work. Make sure you do not edit text2 in the TextChanged listener because then afterTextChanged would get called again.

```
final EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
final EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
final EditText text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text3);

text2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        text3.setText(text1.getText().toString() + text2.getText().toString());
    };
});
```

Comment: @Tiru Good. You should accept the answer if it is what you needed.

Comment: @Robby, why are the EditText variables declared as final?

Comment: Local variables must be declared final when being used inside the anonymous inner class (TextWatcher).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to detect when your two EditText fields change, you're going to need to use [addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) on each of them. The following can go in your onCreate() method:

```
final EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
final EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
final EditText text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text3);

TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        text3.setText(text1.getText() + text2.getText());
    };
});

text1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
text2.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Comment: I tried this method also, but I could not get the value in third EditText field.

Comment: did you implement a TextWatcher add use addTextChangedListener() ? Please include your activity code in your question.

Comment: Is there require to add OnClickListner methods ?

Comment: I did not implement any thing. I am new in Android.So I don't know.Pleas give any site that I learn it.

Comment: My Activity class is as below

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.tiru;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SetEditText extends Activity {

    private String mtext1 = null;
    private String mtext2 = null;
    private String mtext3 = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        mtext1 = text1.getText();
        mtext2 = text2.getText();
        mtext3 = mtext1 + mtext2;
        EditText text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text3);
        text3.setText(mtext3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText inputWeight,inputHeight,outputResult;
Button calculate;
float num1,num2,out;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi);

    inputWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
    inputHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
    outputResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);
    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cal);


    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            num1 = Float.parseFloat(inputWeight.getText().toString());
            num2 = Float.parseFloat(inputHeight.getText().toString());
            out=num1/(num2*num2);
            calculate.setText(" "+out);
        }
    });}
```